# how to define many-to-one bi-directional relationship in xsd so that hyperjaxb3 can generate correct entity classes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hyperjaxb

I have to define a bi-directional many-to-one relationship in xml schema , which hyperjaxb3 is using to generate the entity classes.

when I tried to reference both the entities within each entity declaration , class conversion throws an exception.

I am using maven as build tool . Please suggest.

Comment: Docs for any JPA implementation would include orm.xml for a N-1 such as this http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/orm/many_to_one.html   Why is it hard to find for your implementations docs?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. Relevant schema fragments, bining/customization and the complete stack trace. Right now it is not possible to answer.